# "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when running a Jest test with Vue Js

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I followed this tutorial https://frontstuff.io/build-your-first-vue-js-component to build a vue js component.
I then followed this tutorial https://frontstuff.io/unit-test-your-first-vuejs-component to unit test the component. 
The unit test fails at the import statement on the component and returns this error:

> ● Test suite failed to run

```
C:\Users\SHINIGAMI-ALFSABAH\Documents\Workspace\Dev\Vue\star-rating\node_modules\vue-awesome\icons\star.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import Icon from '../components/Icon.vue'
                                                                                         ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  12 | 
  13 | <script>
> 14 |     import 'vue-awesome/icons/star'
     | ^
  15 |     import Icon from 'vue-awesome/components/Icon'
  16 | 
  17 |     export default {

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
  at src/components/Rating.vue:14:1
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Rating.vue:67:3)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found an answer on SO from a previous similar question [Unexpected token 'import' error while running Jest tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127176/unexpected-token-import-error-while-running-jest-tests)

Basically I had to change my transformIgnorePatterns array in my jest config from:

`transformIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/"],`

to

`transformIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/(?!vue-awesome)"],`

making sure jest compiles 'vue-awesome' module to use in the test.

Answer (score 6):

What I did was I installed the dependencies needed for vue and jest to work together, then I created a config file for babel and jest.

```
//Installing dependencies for jest and vue js
npm i -D @vue/test-utils jest vue-jest @vue/babel-preset-app babel-core@^7.0.0-bridge.0
```

```
//jest.config.js
module.exports = {
    moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'json', 'vue'],
    transform: {
        ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest",
        "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
    }
};
```

```
//babel.config.js
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        '@vue/app'
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a missing `name:`  field in the components that it was having trouble with, and then clearing the jest cache.